# Program to remove comments

Tags: lex

I would like to write a programm in LEX that removes comments from input. Comments could be written in these ways:

- `/*comment*/`
- `//comment`
- `/*comment /*comment*/ */`

My idea is:
Recognize some way if input starts with `/*` -> then I will look for `/*` and ignore text inside. If input starts with `//`, I will ignore it until end of line.

But I don't know exactly how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Lex patterns alone can't handle nested comments, so you'll need to handle the recursive nature of nesting with the Lex states (or write a recursive descent parser).

With lex, use the state stack management routines ( `yy_push_state()`, `yy_pop_state()` and `yy_top_state()` )

Simple example:

```
%x BLOCKCOMMENT

"/*"                 { yy_push_state(BLOCKCOMMENT); }
<BLOCKCOMMENT>"*/"   { if(yy_top_state() == BLOCKCOMMENT)
                           yy_pop_state();
                       else
                           fprintf(stderr,
                            "Error: comment close `*/` found while not in comment\n");
                     }
<BLOCKCOMMENT>.      { /* consume */ }

.                    { return yytext[0]; }
```